# android studio gradle sync error

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, synchronization

After trying a preview version that gave me odd errors, i just did a fresh install of Android Studio 1.1.0 on Ubuntu Linux.
I also removed the preferences directory to start from scratch.

Now even with new projects gradle sync fails with this error and i cannot find the cause or other informations that can give me hints about the cause:

```
Error:Cause: org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.tooling.ModelBuilderService: Provider org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.tooling.builder.ExternalProjectBuilderImpl not found
```

Does anybody knows how to fix this?

Comment: Try closing Android Studio, manually removing all `build` folders and `.iml` files, and reimport the project into AS.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Solved by deleting the $HOME/.gradle folder.

I guess executing the preview version messed up something there.

Comment: Deleting just the caches subdirectory in this folder worked fine for me.

Comment: Deleting `caches` alone didn't help in my case, had to wipe out the whole `~/.gradle` directory. Also in my project directory ran `find . -name "*.iml" -delete` to delete all *.iml files; and `rm -rf .idea/`. The issue happened after I have tried Android Studio 1.2 preview.

Comment: May be I am stupid....but just in case someone misunderstand as I do. $HOME/.gradle means your home directory on the OS, not the project root folder.

Comment: Adding an additional scenario: I tried to downgrade my AS installation by overwriting the installation on a Mac. This solved the errors.

Comment: I did as @DenisKniazhev described, and also `rm -rf build` or `./gradlew clean`.

Answer (score 0):

I had to delete the .AndroidStudioPreview, .gradle/ and the .android. Basically it's like to uninstall android studio, but it worked for me.